# SQL SERVER : How to make query from XML file

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have two xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<instance xmlns="http://www.ubrea.com/xforms/88668970-6edb-0131-28e9-22000a1cda92" xmlns:tm="http://www.ubrea.com/xforms" >
<inputs>
<Truck_Number_Non_Barcode>MNKSJJHDHH88728</Truck_Number_Non_Barcode>
<VIN>
  <Non_Barcode>xyz</Non_Barcode>
  <ODO>1425788</ODO> 
  <Defect>
    <Code>33J</Code>
</Defect> 
</VIN>
</inputs>
</instance>
```

And

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<instance xmlns="http://www.ubrea.com/xforms/88668970-6edb-0131-28e9-22000a1cda92" xmlns:tm="http://www.ubrea.com/xforms" >
<inputs>
<Number_Non_Barcode>mnbcdsddsd3455</Number_Non_Barcode>
<VIN>
  <Non_Barcode>xyz</Non_Barcode>
  <ODO>1425788</ODO>      
</VIN>
</inputs>
</instance>
```

Below is my sqlquery for parsing xml file:

```
declare @xmldata xml
set @xmldata ='
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<instance xmlns="http://www.ubrea.com/xforms/88668970-6edb-0131-28e9-22000a1cda92" xmlns:tm="http://www.ubrea.com/xforms" >
<inputs>
<Number_Non_Barcode>mnbcdsddsd3455</Number_Non_Barcode>
<VIN>
  <Non_Barcode>xyz</Non_Barcode>
  <ODO>1425788</ODO>      
</VIN>
</inputs>
</instance>'
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @xmlns varchar(max)
set @xmlns=''''+SUBSTRING(cast(@xmldata as varchar(max)),CHARINDEX('http://www.ubrea.com/xforms/',cast(@xmldata as varchar(max)),1),CHARINDEX('" xmlns:dm',cast(@xmldata as varchar(max)),1)-18)+''''
set @sql='
declare @xmldata xml
set @xmldata = '''+cast(@xmldata as varchar(max))+'''
begin try
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES 
(
    DEFAULT ' + @xmlns +
     ','+'''http://www.ubrea.com/xforms''' + ' as fm 
)
select
    Number_Non_Barcode, Non_Barcode, ODO, Code
from (
select          
    x.c.value(''(../../Number_Non_Barcode)[1]'', ''varchar(100)'') as Number_Non_Barcode,       
    x.c.value(''(../Non_Barcode)[1]'', ''varchar(100)'') as Non_Barcode,
    x.c.value(''(../ODO)[1]'', ''varchar(100)'') as ODO,
    x.c.value(''(Code)[1]'', ''varchar(100)'') as Code      
from @xmldata.nodes(''/instance/inputs/VIN/Defect'') x(c)
) x  

end try
begin catch
select ERROR_NUMBER() Code, ERROR_MESSAGE() Message
end catch'
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

How to make Query if `<Defect>` not available and the result should like this:

```
Number_Non_Barcode  Non_Barcode   ODO         Defect_Code
mnbcdsddsd3455      xyz           1425788      NULL
```

I'm not real familiar with xml query and can't seem to find an example of how to do it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you have a query that works as expected if `Defect` **is** available?

Comment: i have shown my query, kindly you can check what's goin on with my code. thanks

Comment: Can any of your nodes repeat leading to multiple rows I the result set or will you always have one row returned? For example if you have multiple 'defect` nodes?

Comment: if found some defects, it will continue in the new line. but if there were no defects it will return NULL

Comment: Ok, is it only defects that repeat or can VIN or Inputs also repeat?

Comment: All fields will be repeated with different defect code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that your dynamic query is there because the default namespace is unknown to you. Instead you can specify the namespace in the XQuery using `*`.

Using the parent axis `..` can be avoided by shredding the XML using `nodes()` and `cross apply` in several steps. Since the `Defect` node can be missing you have to use `outer apply` when shredding those nodes.

```sql
select I.X.value('(*:Number_Non_Barcode/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Number_Non_Barcode,
       V.X.value('(*:Non_Barcode/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Non_Barcode,
       V.X.value('(*:ODO/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as ODO,
       D.X.value('(*:Code/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Code
from @XMLData.nodes('/*:instance/*:inputs') as I(X)
  cross apply I.X.nodes('*:VIN') as V(X)
  outer apply V.X.nodes('*:Defect') as D(X)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/30978)