# Reading XML repeated tags in sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xml-parsing, sqlxml

```
 Declare @MainXml XML = 
 '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <result>
 <cash number="10">
 <account amt="11.00" status="Closed"/>
 <account amt="12.00" status="Closed"/>                       
 </cash>        
 <cash number="20">
 <account amt="21.00" status="Closed"/>
 <account amt="22.00" status="Closed"/>                       
 </cash>        
 </result>'
```

I am reading data using following query

```
Declare @Innerxml xml; 
SELECT @Innerxml = T.c.query('<result>{/result/cash}</result>')
FROM   @MainXml.nodes('result') T(c)

SELECT  
Result.Claim.value('(./@number)[1]','varchar(max)') as C1,
Result.Claim.value('(./@amt)[1]','varchar(max)') as C2,
Result.Claim.value('(./@status)[1]','varchar(max)') as C3   
From @Innerxml.nodes('/result/cash/account') Result(Claim)
```

I want to read the xml and store in DB as below.

```
C1   C2     C3
----------------
10   11.00  Closed
10   12.00  Closed
20   21.00  Closed
20   22.00  Closed
```

but my query returns only NULL in C1 column
Please help me here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the parent axis in XML queries in SQL Server. The query plan created will be O(n<sup>2</sup>). For every node in the XML all nodes in the XML is checked.

First shred on `result/cash` and then shred on `account` in a cross apply.

```sql
select C.X.value('@number', 'varchar(max)') as C1,
       A.X.value('@amt', 'varchar(max)') as C2,
       A.X.value('@status', 'varchar(max)') as C3
from @MainXml.nodes('result/cash') as C(X)
  cross apply C.X.nodes('account') as A(X)
```

<sub>I don't see the point of creating a second XML variable. Use `@MainXML` directly.</sub>

Comment: While it sounds logical, I'm not sure this is always true. I reckon I've seen queries with `..` sometimes performed better than ones with several applies like this, but I don't have any exact example at the moment. That said, it would be interesting to test it

Comment: Also I disagree that plan will be `O(n^2)`, it should be linear, because every node has only one parent

Comment: @RomanPekar have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196516/cross-apply-xml-query-performs-exponentially-worse-as-xml-document-grows

Comment: thanks, nice answer! As I said, it makes perfect sense that it's better to shred xml like you did here and this is always my first try, I just rememeber that I've seen the situations where parent node works better, but again, no example for now.

Comment: @RomanPekar perhaps you had a XML index in place? The plan is different if you do.

Comment: nope, I think I once seen an answer on SO where parent nodes performed better and it could also be heavily nested xml I've used to work. I'll try to check if I can create an example

Comment: Thanks Mikael for detail discussion

Answer (score 2):

`@number` is attribute of `<cash>` but your context node is `<account>`. You need to go up the XML tree one level to get to `<cash>` node before accessing the attribute. You can do `..` to get to parent of current node in xpath :

```
SELECT  
Result.Claim.value('(../@number)[1]','varchar(max)') as C1,
Result.Claim.value('(./@amt)[1]','varchar(max)') as C2,
Result.Claim.value('(./@status)[1]','varchar(max)') as C3   
From @Innerxml.nodes('/result/cash/account') Result(Claim)
```