# Transform XML record to table

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I have XML data in table "sample" column name "xmlrec" that looks like:

```xml
<row id='1'>
 <c1>rec1</c1>
 <c2>a</c2>
 <c2>b</c2>
 <c2>c</c2>
</row>
```

The same needs to be transformed as below:

```
c1      c2
----    ----
rec1    a
rec1    b
rec1    c
```

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY xmlrec.nodes('/row/c2')` to find all `c2` nodes. Finding the corresponding `c1` is easy:

```
SELECT n.value('(../c1)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS c1
     , n.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS c2
FROM sample
CROSS APPLY xmlrec.nodes('/row/c2') AS x(n)
```

Comment: Exactly what i was about to post. +1 from me.

Comment: Not exactly the same but this query suffers from the same issues as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24199428/569436).

Comment: Thanks all for the solution. It worked.. I have adopted below solution  SELECT n.value('(../c1)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS c1
     , n.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS c2
FROM sample
CROSS APPLY xmlrec.nodes('/row/c2') AS x(n)

Answer (score 3):

I'd prefer forward-navigation. It is possible to use `../c1` as in the other answer, but - as far as I know - performance is not the best. This is an alternative:

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<row id="1">
 <c1>rec1</c1>
 <c2>a</c2>
 <c2>b</c2>
 <c2>c</c2>
</row>';

SELECT A.r.value('@id','int') AS row_id
      ,A.r.value('(c1/text())[1]','nvarchar(10)') AS c1
      ,B.c2.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(10)') AS c2
FROM @xml.nodes('/row') A(r)
CROSS APPLY A.r.nodes('c2') B(c2);
```

If there is only one `<row>` within your XML, this was best

```
SELECT @xml.value('(/row/@id)[1]','int') AS row_id
      ,@xml.value('(/row/c1/text())[1]','nvarchar(10)') AS c1
      ,B.c2.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(10)') AS c2
FROM @xml.nodes('/row/c2') B(c2);
```

Comment: + 1 "performance is not the best" I wrote something about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24199428/569436)

Comment: @MikaelEriksson I did read your brilliant answer a while ago and had this in mind, when I posted this hint :-) But I did not remember the link, thanks for passing by!