# SQL XML parsing different nodes

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

i would like to ask you for help with parsing XML in SQL, where my XML looks like this, where Load is parrent which can be repeated X-times. I need Column SerNr and for each row need to bound Order name 
where final table will looks like this

Example of table:

[image: screenshot example of table]

```
<ImageHistory>    
    <Load targets="2" totalTime="417">
    <Orders>
    <Order name="20548976"/>
    </Orders>
    <Data>
    <Disk SerNr="XXXXXX" Size_mb="228936" LoadSuccessfull="true" /> 
    <Disk SerNr="ZZZZZ" Size_mb="228936" LoadSuccessfull="true" /> 
    </Data>
    </Load>
    </ImageHistory>
```

sql is

```
with data as (SELECT CAST(MY_XML AS xml) as MY_XML FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'addres to xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MY_XML)), 
datainfo as (
SELECT
MY_XML.Blasting.value(' @name', 'BIGINT') as Size_mb,
MY_XML.Blasting.value('@SerNr', 'varchar(32)') as SerNr
FROM data CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes('ImageHistory/Load/Data/Disk') AS MY_XML (Blasting))
select * from datainfo
```

thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saved the XML as a file on the file system: *e:\Temp\DiskSerialNumbers.xml*
The rest is below.

> SQL

```
;WITH XmlFile (Contents) AS
(
   SELECT CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) 
   FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'e:\Temp\DiskSerialNumbers.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS XmlData
)
SELECT c.value('(../../Orders/Order/@name)[1]', 'INT') AS [Name]
    , c.value('@SerNr', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS [SerNr]
FROM XmlFile CROSS APPLY Contents.nodes('/ImageHistory/Load/Data/Disk') AS t(c);
```

> Output

```
+----------+--------+
|   Name   | SerNr  |
+----------+--------+
| 20548976 | XXXXXX |
| 20548976 | ZZZZZ  |
+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Hi Yitzhak, I just added an alternative as backward navigation is a performance killer...

Comment: Hi Shnugo, Good deal. I am very well aware about the backward XPath navigation as a performance killer. The XML sample provided is so small so I didn't bother to use two CROSS APPLY clauses...

Answer (score 0):

You've got your answer already, but I want to point to the fact, that *backward navigation* (using `../../`) is [horribly slow with bigger structures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24199428/5089204).

I'd suggest this:

A *mockup* to simulate your issue:

```
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,YourXml XML);
INSERT INTO @yourTable VALUES 
(N'<ImageHistory>
    <Load targets="2" totalTime="417">
    <Orders>
        <Order name="20548976" />
    </Orders>
    <Data>
        <Disk SerNr="XXXXXX" Size_mb="228936" LoadSuccessfull="true" />
        <Disk SerNr="ZZZZZ" Size_mb="228936" LoadSuccessfull="true" />
    </Data>
    </Load>
</ImageHistory>');
```

--The query

```
SELECT t.ID
        ,ld.value('@targets','int') AS Load_Targets
        ,ld.value('@totalTime','int') AS Load_TotalTime
        ,ld.value('(Orders/Order/@name)[1]','int') AS Order_Name
        ,dsk.value('@SerNr','nvarchar(100)') AS Disk_SerNr
        ,dsk.value('@Size_mb','nvarchar(100)') AS Disk_Size_mb
        ,dsk.value('@LoadSuccessfull','bit') AS Disk_LoadSuccessfull
FROM @yourTable AS t
CROSS APPLY t.YourXml.nodes('/ImageHistory/Load') A(ld)
CROSS APPLY A.ld.nodes('Data/Disk') B(dsk);
```

The idea in short:

The first `APPLY` will dive down to `<Load>` and will return all `<Load>` elements (if there are more...

The second `APPLY` will use the fragment returned by the first `APPLY` and dive deeper down to `<Disk>`.

We fetch the order's name (and other values) calling `.value()` against the first fragment (which is the `<Load>` element) and we fetch the values of `<Disk>` calling `.value()` against the fragment of the second `APPLY`.